# Cumulative flow diagram in AzureDevops - by Area Path

Tags: azure-devops, report, kanban, cmmi

in Azure DevOps, is there a way to generate a report so you can see Cumulative flow diagram (CFD) by Area Path as oppose to Team?

We are using Azure DevOps (CMMI, Kanban) for our work.  In our AzureDevops configuration, we have two teams (to make it simple, I will call it Team A and Team B).  Under each team, we have broken up the work into sub-teams using Area Paths.  For example, Team A is IT Operations Team and the Area Path represents IT Operations sub-teams (e.g., Network Team, Help Desk, Linux Server Support, etc.).  Our Team B is Line of Biz applications and the sub-teams are aligned by technology (e.g., DBA, CRM, etc).

The CFD Widget in Azure Devops doesn't allow you to view the CFD by the Area Path, it will just view it at the AzureDEvops Team level (Team A or Team B).

It looks like the CFD widget is out of the question, is there an alternate way to gather CFD information by Area Path in AzureDevops?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid Azure Devops doesn't support viewing the CFD by the Area Path currently.

However, As a workaround you can create a [Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/query-by-area-iteration-path?view=azure-devops) to filter the work items by area path and then create a Chart similar to CFD and add to the dashboard. See below example:

1, Create a Query in the Queries section to filter the work items by area path.

[image]

2, Go the **Charts** tab, Click **New chart**, Choose the **Stacked area** chart type, Choose Stack by **State**.

[image]

Another workaround is to create new teams for each sub-team(ie. Network Team, Help Desk, Linux Server Support, etc.). Then select the **sub area path**  in the [Team Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-area-paths?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#open-team-settings-list-team-area-paths) page for these new teams.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the details.  I will check out the Charts.